# Does MS Graph API support Microsoft 365 Defender

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365-defender

I cannot find a document on the MS Graph support pages for Microsoft 365 Defender.
I would like to configure the following policies using MS Graph

- Anti-phishing
- Anti-spam
- Anti-malware

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does offer security API which touches on defender, but I don't think it's possible to set configure polices at present:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

This seems to be still under development as you are encouraged to file issues to fill in feature gaps.

Comment: Thanks, I have filed an issue to request support for configuring these policies.

Answer (score 0):

There is Microsoft Graph Security API which a unified interface and schema to integrate with security solutions from Microsoft and ecosystem partners.

Unfortunately I do not see any possibility how to configure the mentioned policies.

Reference:

[Security API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)